# Can a Chrome/whatever Extension return clicked DOM elements?

Tags: angular, google-chrome-extension

I wanted to write some sort of overlay I could, well, lay over any website so it'd track user input and loading times, in order to automatically create automated tests with Selenium  later.

Initially, I tried using an iframe inside an Angular app and built on top of it a pretty nice-looking overlay, only to discover that there's no way I'd be able to read the HTML inside a cross-domain website. Too bad, really, 'cause I just needed to identify the clicked DOM, that's all.

So now I'm considering making it into a Chrome extension, that's why I wanted to ask you:

- can a Chrome extension return HTMLElements from a click event?
- if yes, how can I get Angular to listen to these fired events?

Thanks!

Comment: is this a builin chrome-devtools tool you are looking for https://umaar.com/dev-tips/241-puppeteer-recorder/ ?

Comment: Extensions can use a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) which runs in the page so it can listen to DOM events. You'll have to process the elements in the content script without "returning" because elements can't be transferred between cross-origin contexts.